# Array from file - edit - write to file

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, fwrite

I have a php file with an array.
It’s a language file.

de.lang.php

```
<?php
$lang['one'] = "one";
$lang['two'] = "two";
$lang['three'] = "three";
?>
```

lang_func.php

```
include(de.lang.php);
```

output.html

```
<input type="text" name="lang_key" value="$key"/>
<input type="text" name="lang_val" value="$val"/>
```

[Screenshot of output.html (left:key, right:value)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsviN.png)

Next I would like to post the form and push the changes to the file.
Which is the best alternative in php to post the changes to the file where changes took place.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'd recommend reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a better grasp of what is expected when you ask a question. Currently, this is too broad to get a straight answer. Have you tried writing back to the file? Have you run into issues? If so, please explain where and how your attempt failed.

Comment: Don't use "smart quotes" in code.

Comment: `file_put_contents("filename", implode("\n", $lang));`

Comment: @Barmar that code will lose the keys and output just a list of values.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Actually, I thought he's talking about an array of lines read from the file, I shouldn't have used the variable `$lang`. `$line[0] = '$lang[‘one’] = “one”;`

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question, but I am assuming that you are using `include()` or a related statement to read your language file, in this structure:

language.php

```
<?php 
$lang = [
    'one'=>'one',
    'two'=>'two'
];
```

myProgram.php

```
include('language.php`);
// rest of code
```

That being the case you can export the `$lang` array with [var_export()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)

```
$languageFile = "<?php\n".var_export($lang, true);
file_put_contents('filename', $languageFile);
```

Note: trailing `?>` is not required if the file contains only PHP code.